# Is it possible to make a logically consistent set of laws that produces physics similar to that in superhero comics?

Tags: physics, super-powers

I'm not talking about stuff like radiation and mutations. I'm talking about mechanics (for now).

Necessary effects:

With superstrength, you can...

- lift objects weighing many tons without your feet sinking into the ground
- lift heavy objects at arm's length without overbalancing
- lift structures otherwise not capable of supporting their own weight

With superspeed, you can...

- land a supersonic punch without hurting your hand, yet still be vulnerable to bullets
- land a supersonic punch on a normal human without killing them
- run without worrying about the supersonic impacts of your feet making holes in the ground

A "tank/brick" character (strong and tough, not necessarily fast) has to be viable in a fight against a speedster.
That is, the brick's fighting style relies on standing his ground. Without being particularly large or heavy, he must be harder to knock over with a high-speed impact than a normal person.

A brick can make high jumps from a standing start. A speedster can't.

The relation of speed to damaging ability is different than in reality.
Even against normal humans, high-speed or sharp objects can still harm them, but low-speed impacts of massive objects are rather ineffective.

A giant doesn't have a problem with sinking into the ground.

Changing size changes your carrying capacity proportionately. A giant ant can lift many times its body weight; a human reduced to the size of an ant can't.

My initial thoughts / proposals:

The brick able to hold his ground suggests he has (passive or active) increased inertial mass. This in turn suggests that speedsters have decreased inertial mass. That is, it's not that they can generate more kinetic energy, but they can move faster for the same energy. Thus, their punches don't carry as much energy as a mundane object impacting at that speed. Because gravitational mass is unchanged, they can't jump as high as their speed would suggest. However, I don't think this explains why the Hulk *is* able to jump high.

Looking at it a different way, the underlying philosophy isn't "I have more money, so I can buy more." It's "I can buy things at lower prices." Properties of the world appear to matter only relative to your own capabilities. In essence, Superman can lift a car by its bumper not because he's exerting the tons of force needed to lift a car normally (which could tear the bumper off) but because, from his perspective, the car weighs less and he can lift it with less force. Likewise, it's not so much that the Flash moves really fast; it's that everything else is in slow motion from his perspective.

The square-cube stuff fits with this principle: doesn't matter if I get bigger or smaller, this patch of ground is still a flat surface made of the same material, it just looks like it covers a different area. I don't have a physical interpretation of this part, though.

The part about a speedster's punches and the part about mundane weapons might be consistent. It seems that the laws governing collisions are different in the super world. In an inelastic collision, kinetic energy is preferentially absorbed by the slower-moving object. Note this requires an absolute rest frame to be defined. This explains why a speedster isn't at serious risk from collisions with stationary objects. This greatly increases the damage-dealing advantage of high-speed low-mass objects over low-speed high-mass ones, creating broadly the correct effect in mundane combat. It explains the Juggernaut's unstoppable charge (or for that matter, the bus in Speed being able to ram cars with impunity - non-superhero action movies share a lot of these physics), and that bullets don't deform on impact.

This is just to show what I've considered already. Some may be redundant, some is insufficient, and I haven't fully reasoned out the other consequences of these. That's what I'm asking for help with.

Always assume a weak anthropic principle. Whatever laws this universe operates on, it must be able to have planets and recognizable life.

To clarify, given the direction the answers are taking:

The objective is not to justify super-powers in our universe. The idea is that even normal humans experience many things differently, since superhero physics appear to be a special case of action-adventure physics.

I recognized from the start that many super-powers make more sense as psionics. I neglected to mention that because I thought I made clear the approach I was taking. I want physical super-powers to be a consequence of, not an exception to, this world's standard physics.

Comment: I don't know if this really helps, but the handwaves given by comic books tend to be along the lines of characters drawing energy or mass from a parallel universe, (like Cyclops's eye blasts or Colossus's metal) or having the ability to alter the laws of physics around them (like with The Flash's "Speed Force"). That, or it's explicity magic or godlike ability.

Comment: The problem with the theory that Supes is draining mass when he swings a car is that it would then be like being hit with nothing when he hits the villain with it.

Comment: @Oldcat Ahem I always wondered how the villains got back up :)... I think the mass might return after he releases it, considering the number of particles it consists of has not changed.

Comment: Your proposals would most likely put the super heroes into some sort of parallel universe where they can feel our universe but the physical laws (whatever they may be) in the other universe apply to them.....caught in between universes.

Comment: One thing that would probably be worth adding to the question is to make sure people explain how the surrounding environment survives super abilities.  How does the flash not create a sonic boom that kills people, same with superman.  How does the ground beneath the hulk's feet not give way when he is lifting ridiculously heavy stuff...if you want consistent physics this needs to be addressed.

Comment: @DustinJackson - I'm sure Supes has swung and hit someone with a big object without letting go in the last 75 years or so.

Comment: One solution is to move the setting from the real world to an imaginary world, where some of these laws don't exist. A "virtual reality" of some sort. This could be a computer generated, magic, spiritual, mental or dream world.

Comment: @Clearer - I'm talking about an alternate world, but specifically a physical one. You know what inspired this question? Tactile telekinesis, as mentioned in dsollen's answer. I was trying to get around needing that.

Answer (score 30):

My answer is really similar to dsollen's, but I think there's enough added that I'll go ahead and post it.

The key here is your statement:

> Properties of the world appear to matter only relative to your own capabilities.

**And the solution is that all superpowers are psychic powers**.

Which is to say that normally when you classify superpowers you might put them into logically categories like physical (strength, speed, toughness), psychic (mind reading, telekinesis), magic (ritual, fireballs), and so on.  But what if instead all powers are actually just psychic, and are driven solely by the user's mind?

This solves a lot of problems.  **Awesome Lass** isn't actually super strong.  If you take a sample of her muscle tissue, you wont' find it any different than tissue from Suzy Sue, intrepid reporter at the Periodic Comet - it's just basic muscle.  But Awesome Lass can lift a car, and Suzy can't, because Awesome Lass has powers and *knows* she can lift a car.  And this explains why she can lift it by the bumper, when logically she should just rip it off - her power is driven by her mental framework.  Even if she later learns that she should be ripping the bumper off when she lifts, she knows she's done it in the past.  Alternatively, her friend **Strongadacious Dude** was originally a physics major, and he can't lift cars by their bumpers because he knows how it should work - he has to find the center of mass.

The neat thing about this is it allows powers to be logically inconsistent, because they are largely based on individual human knowledge and expectations.  **Speedy Guy** *should* be able to block a bullet just like he blocks the wind at Mach 10, but that doesn't have anything to do with Speedy Guy's perception of his power, so it doesn't work.  **Stupendous Sally** should sink into the ground since she's 50-feet tall, but her power holds her up and lets her ignore the pesky problems with the square-cube law.

There are some interesting implications of this approach:

1. Ignorance = flexibility.  Knowledge = power.  Awesome Lass can lift a car by a bumper because she doesn't know any better, but she's doing it the hard way - her power has to help balance and hold the car together instead of just lifting.  Strongadacious Dude is lifting directly, which means he's using his power more efficiently - which means he can lift twice as much as Awesome Lass, as long as he takes things like structure and the center of balance into account.  Speedy Guy can run through a city at Mach 10 without blocking out windows from a sonic boom, because that's not part of his power.  But his rival **Superfast Fellow** can go Mach 15 and block bullets just like wind - but he does a ton of property damage at the same time.
2. You might see additional powers develop over time, as situations occur where heroes (or villains) need them.  Suddenly Speedy Guy can lift a car, because that's the only way to save his wife.  Alternatively, people might learn how to use their powers more efficiently over time subconsciously, so they'll get stronger overall.
3. It might be possible to lose powers as you learn more.  So maybe once Awesome Lass figures out she shouldn't be able to lift cars that way, suddenly she can't.  This could go so far as to having heroes lose their abilities entirely.

The final thing you need to worry about here is a power source.  I would probably go with some sort of handwaved tap into dark energy - we know it exists, maybe superpowers let people tap into that to do superhuman feats.  Alternatively, maybe heroes have a direct matter-energy conversions engine organ - extremely dangerous, but lots of power.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. It allows for most of the various training tropes. Particularly difficult tasks, repetitive and mundane tasks, or just exercises in mental discipline can make you stronger/better. Also, you could get some amazing [Achievements in Ignorance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AchievementsInIgnorance).

Comment: I like this answer.  If you haven't already, I suggest you read the "Gil Hamilton" stories by Larry Niven, which somewhat include ideas along these lines.  Gil Hamilton suffered the loss of an arm in an accident, and one day dropped something and tried to catch it with his missing hand... and succeeded.  He had developed telekinesis with the limitations that his range was only the length of his missing arm.  Later he uses his arm to "touch" a 3D image of the surface of the moon, and he searches several square kilometres by touch.  He has powers based on how his mind thinks an arm should work.

Comment: Secret Psionics for the win!

Comment: +1 for Gil . His power was reliable because it was believable to him - it was just his arm - versus feats by his peers that were more spectacular but less reliable.

Comment: Incidentally, the ability to lift cars by their bumpers once made sense as they used to be bolted directly to the frame. My dad's 1962 chevy was jacked from the bumper, so that's half the car's weight right there.

Comment: During his mid 1980s run on the Fantastic Four comic series writer artist John Byrne postulated a very similar idea. In one issue of the series he had a character called Gladiator (a thinly veiled version of Superman) lift an entire skyscraper. Realizing that the building would collapse under its own weight he suggested that Gladiator was actually exerting a kind telekinetic force that allowed him to lift the building and keep it from crumbling apart. In essence he was lifting the building with his mind as much as his physical strength. So "all powers are actually psychic powers" gets my vote.

Comment: This answer makes me think of Maxima from grrlpower - this is kind of her thing.

Comment: The _source_ of powers is different, but the effects you list here are really close to the rules in [All Those Explosions Were Someone Else's Fault](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33517573-all-those-explosions-were-someone-else-s-fault).  Heroes' superpowers are defined over time as they believe they can or can't do things, and the more they think about _how_ it works, the less it does.

Answer (score 5):

This is a *really* tall order.  I don't think you can really get a fully logically consistent physics.  The best you can do is a hand wave that sounds plausible enough that people don't think too deeply.

My best idea for the BRICK would be to go with the concept that is canonically superboy's power set, tactile telekinesis.  They are not super-strong, but instead of a form of telekinesis that is limited.  They must touch the object to exert their telekinesis, either because the field must expand out from their body to work or because they lack conscious control of the telekinesis and so their subconscious is using it tactile only.

This solves a huge number of problems that come up with super-strength.  It explains why someone doesn't sink into the ground when they lift something hard, why the airplane's wings don't snap off when they try to lift the plan by it's wing, why the equal & opposite forces of throwing a gigantic rock at someone don't result in their being tossed backwards into a building etc etc.

A similar explanation can be used for their super-suitability.  The same telekinetic field could be surrounding them.  speedsters can't knock them over because they are using their telekinesis to hold themselves up!

The speedster could be explained with a similar approach, though it works a little less with him.  Perhaps he propels himself with a similar sort of telekinesis ?  It works better if instead of moving his legs super fast he simply hovers centimeters above the ground and pushes himself at high speeds.  Of course this is more limited then the traditional speedster concept, he wouldn't be able to read or type at a computer at super speed for instance.  Furthermore if he didn't have super-evolved reflexes he would still be quite vulnerable to anything that would force him to move quickly.  His telekinesis may allow him to stop or turn fast when used, but he is still limited by his slow human-mind in recognizing threats and adjusting.

The speedster can survive hitting things with massive force because he doesn't hit them, his telekinesis does.  perhaps that spreads the force from his one fist across his entire body, slowing him down rapidly but lowering the impact on any one point to a manageable level.

I think this approach works best if we explain the differences in telekinesis control coming down to the concept of "the human mind can't fully comprehend telekinesis "  In theory it would be possible to fling spaceships by looking at them, but we haven't evolved to be able to do that and no one really knows how to make themselves do it.  Instead we use our telekinesis to enhance things that come naturally to us anyways and subconsciously the telekinesis 'just works'

Of course, one still needs to explain where the telekinesis came from.  Honestly I'm half tempted to suggest you don't try to explain any further.  Saying "we figured out how to make telekinesis work" is one single hand-wave that you can get people to accept due to suspension of disbelief.  Set consistent rules for how it works and just explain them.  Trying to explain exactly how the telekinesis works further is likely to do more harm to suspension of disbelief then good, since once you bring up specifics people think about it harder and realize all the reasons it doesn't work.

However, if you do wish to try to go into more specifics, using modern physics, lets try something like this:

In the near future we have a revolutionary scientific breakthrough about how to control forces around us.  We discover how to use a device to convert physical energy into potential energy and back again rapidly.  It does this by projecting a special field of waves around the objects, and it can absorb or transfer energy across anything that passes through this field.

The really interesting thing here is to abide by thermodynamics and conservation of energy, which implies some cool limits to your superheroes.  Imagine that your Tank goes in with a mostly full 'battery' of energy powering his field.  When he lifts up a car and throws it he needs to transfer a significant amount of kinetic energy into the car to counteract gravity to lift it up.  He can throw the car at someone by converting more of his potential energy into kinetic, the equal & opposite recoil doesn't occur because that kinetic energy is converted to potential.  He will be using up lots of kinetic energy as he throws items around.

However, when the speedster runs up and hits him with supersonic force his field does the opposite, converting kinetic energy into potential energy.  This recharges his 'battery' partially, giving him more energy to fuel his car throwing later.  If he every uses up his 'battery' entirely he will be merely human.

As the speedster keeps being hit by punches from the tank he converts that energy into potential.  However, his capacitor is limited as well, and eventually if he absorbs too much energy it can be over loaded and go boom.  so no soaking up punches forever.

Of course entropy means that energy will have to be constantly lost with these exchanges.  if they just trade punches back and forth both's batteries will slowly degrade as more and more of that energy dissipates due to entropy, maybe expanded across the entire electromagnetic spectrum to spread it out enough that it isn't harmful to anyone nearby (plus it's cool that a really strong punch actually causes a bit of a light flash that humans can see lol).

To further limit superheros from trading punches back and forth forever you could also imply that this device requires a unique fuel source, and they use it up as they trade energy.  Thus the speedster isn't too worried that he is 'feeding' energy to the tank by hitting him, because he is still wasting the tanks 'fuel' by forcing him to have to convert between kinetic and potential energy.

Lets also put an upper bound on how fast one can convert between energy sources.  If you get hit with a hard enough strike your field won't be able to covert the kinetic force into potential energy fast enough.  Your going to feel the impact and be hurt by a powerful blow as some of the kinetic energy slips past your field and hits you.  The more energy that your hit with the more that slips by, but it's not linear.  If you get hit with X energy maybe 0.1x of it will slip through your field.  if you get hit by 2x 0.15 slips through.  10x force lets 0.2 through etc; more force means more impact, but it's not where you can absorb exactly X without difficulty and anything over X will be fatal.

The other question is why we would use this to be superheros, when the technology has so many other applications.  This is a real issue with almost any approach you use to justify superheroics.  The best explination I have is that the power is limited to human minds and we use it the only way our minds know how to; theoretically it could be used other ways but we don't yet know how to harness it as such.  For instance try out this scenario.

When they discover this amazing technology they also find a key weakness.  Their best computer simulations are incapable of doing the calculations required to figure out how to exert this field accurately.  Limitations on how we do calculations mean we are unable to generate a proper model quickly enough and thus we apply the energy translation field unevenly.  This tends to result on very different forces being exerted across the body of an object, which ultimately lead to tearing it apart in a very unpleasant manner.  It's unsafe to use computer controlled fields.

However, there are certain processes that human mind does *much* better then computers today (vision recognition, facial recognition, spacial orientation/awareness etc).  In the near future we have not gotten any better at making computers do these sort of processes, thus the failed fails.  However, in this near-future we have started to figure out the basis of computer to neural interface, connecting computers into our brains.  Thus machines to control these fields are connected into the human mind.  The human minds own unique processing ability is used to supplement the computers and do those calculations computers are still terrible at.

The problem is that the human minds are not human computers, we can't just plug into a human mind and tell it "figure this out for me".  Instead we need to 'trick' the human mind into doing it's own process recognition and have the computers 'listen in' for the answer to the calculations it needs.  This results in computers only being able to apply the field to those things that the human mind is already thinking about and processing correctly.  Effectively TANKS are able to lift objects because when they are lifting the objects they already are calculating its position, shape, etc etc and the computer can use that processed information to power the field.  In short the reason that we can't do even more with these fields is that we can only do what we can trick our minds into thinking we should be able to do...

Your speedster and tank are both using the same technology, but applying it in different ways.  They would likely need extensive training to learn how to 'think right' to interface with the devices; and each was trained in using them in different manners.  They both would likely receive similar protection from blunt force trauma because they have an awareness of their body and their minds can project an *absorb the energy from that punch quick* thought.  However, bullets are so small and fast that the brain does not have time to process them, and so the computer can't use the field to absorb or redirect their kinetic energy.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want a new physics, not new power explanations. So, I'll avoid all physic/telekinesis that aren't really explained by physics.  That means that we have to stop thinking about super heroes and think about structures.

If physics allows for a superhero to life a massive object without transferring the force to the ground below him... it must be possible to build some sort of structure that does the same.

Also changing the laws of physics in a particular place but not in the rest of the universe aren’t allowed either, we need a new physics that allows for superpowers but all other phenomena still works... from the stars to live, it all appears to be the same as in our world.

It is time to create a new particle!

---

### The superpower particle

It works like this: when an electron interacts with a superpower particle, they merge into a new particle that interacts with the nucleus the same way that electron does… but has an additional “superpower” charge. Let’s call that particle “power electron”.

We are used to think that the boulder transfers its weight to the superhuman and the superhuman to the ground, but in reality the force is transferred molecule to molecule causing heat and deformation – if not rupture – along the way.
When the electrons of the molecules come close they exchange virtual photons that push the electrons back (they repel※). they are both pushed back with equivalent force as per Newton’s third law of motion. We don’t want that! We want the power electron to experience no acceleration while the electron moves back.

※: the electrons absorb the photons; this causes them to have more energy moving (become more excited) them to a higher orbital (heating the molecule). Now the electrons are further away from the nuclei and closed together, but they can’t share space… so, they either find a shared orbital (creating a bond) or increase the distance between the molecules (pushing them apart, I suspect this is Lorentz force, but that’s at the edge of my knowledge). If they didn’t create a bond the electrons are no longer in equilibrium and they will spontaneously release a photon and fallback to their previous orbital. And that’s how heat agitates the molecules, but we are not talking about that.

The mechanism I propose for that is as follows: if photons of the right frequency interact with the power electron it will absorb the photon, release the superpower particle, and that will quickly decay into a photon equivalent to the one that entered and probably another photon or a neutrino (not sure which works better). When electron and the power electron exchange of virtual photons, they trigger the release of the “superpower” particle effectively negating the effect of the photon on the power electron and sending it back to the original electron. After the interaction the power electron has been dissociated and a regular electron is left in its place. In practice the molecule with power electron behaves as if it had more inertia but not more mass…

We are hacking relativity: Running at near sonic speed towards a metal slug is not the same as a metal slug moving at near sonic speed towards you… if you have superpower particles. Also inertial mass and gravitational mass are no longer indistinguishable… if you have superpower particles.

---

Now, the superhero must be charged with superpower particles that would be used as needed. The more superpower particles the greater the feats the superhero can do. Yet, the superhero needs to replenish his superpower particles…
This comes to the problem of how you generate superpower particles. Usually I would say that you need them to be a result of phenomena too energetic as to have been discovered by humans with current technology…

But you can always go with the trope of the superhero with powers from radiation and say that these particles can be created by already known technology such as atomic bombs or particle accelerators, just not in large enough quantities… but then someday they were experimenting with some new equipment and there was an accident and you have your next speedster or tank!

These need a mutation that allows for the generation of superpower particles in their bodies. I would probably suggest the interaction of a free superpower particle with photons may cause the photon to turn into another superpower particle of equivalent energy. So, as long as the superpower particles don’t run down to nil, they can multiplicity in some organelle in the mutated cells – something similar to the mitochondria.

There may be a prophecy of a child born with a high number of mutated mitochondria who will bring equilibrium to the superpowers… but I digress…
Aside from the superheroes form the atomic age, we should consider that if superpower particles can be created by such machinery, they are created in the sun too! Now you can have your next solar deity! This one of course replenishes his powers from the sun. He may be vulnerable to light of the particular frequency that causes his superpower particles to dissociate and decay… maybe generated by some green glowing mineral?

---

Does that mean that watching directly into the sun will give you a power trip? Well, you may become Daredevil :v – The hazards of radiations are still there, and the dosage of superpower particles from the sun may just not provide enough for any practical superpower in the human timespan. With perhaps the exception of some mutation (maybe in the X chromosome?) that allows you to multiply the superpower particles from the sun to usable levels.

But superpower materials could be viable. You just consider a decent sized monolith left untouched for millennia; it probably has accumulated a considerable amount of super power particles. Now you can have your superhero from the Egyptian Pyramids or the Stonehenge.

Also, if it is possible to accidentally create machines that generate large amounts of superpower particles, it is also possible to do it intentionally. You may inject some serum in the bloodstream of a patient that includes some retro-virus that mutates him to multiply superpower particles and then bath him with the particles using a special capsule… Or you can use it to empower materials, perhaps for giant combat robots, or if miniaturization allows, create a small reactor to power an exo-suit.

---

### Power differentiation

If all superpowers come from the abundance of superpower particles… why are there so many different super power sets? Simple: they don’t have the same distribution in the body. For example if they concentrate in the bones, then the bones are super! Super skin for invulnerability, super muscles for super strength, and so on…

No, I don’t think superpower particles in the brain will give you super intelligence (I think it would make new neural connections harder to form)... In fact, I think the presence of superpower particles would temporarily increase the electric impedance of the material. You could get away with saying that it allows to build up electricity and then release as a spark.

And I don’t see how you can explain powers such as shapeshifting, or invisibility with this.

Comment: -1 could have called it the supermon /s

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I really like the other answers, particularly the one by dsollen - but here is an alternative.

A way is discovered to modify the rules of the universe, you actually have a generator of some sort that taps into your body and when activated starts altering fundamental constants. The effect goes through your body and then radiates out from it, with decreasing intensity.

Some of the fields are able to extend out along other solid objects you touch.

The fields themselves are generated by some unique breakthrough, you can insert any suitably intense energy force but fusion or matter-antimatter reactions should be sufficient. The key thing is though the bioelectrical field of a living being is needed to control and contain the force.

The implants can be inserted into animals, and are used for electricity generation and suchlike in that way. Far more interesting though are the military, police, criminal and vigilantes who beg/borrow/steal/build/etc their own implants and fit them to themselves.

These implants themselves are tied to the individual and so some are easier for some people to use than others. Additionally running multiple implants at once becomes exponentially more difficult, so while 1% of the population could theoretically use the implants 1 in 10 of them can use 2, 1 in 100 can use 3, 1 in 1000 can use 4, etc.

But what about the super-powers? Here are some examples (some hand-waving will be needed to explain how the human body manages to keep working in some of these):

Superfast is just that - you modify time around you. For your purposes you are moving and breathing at your usual rate. The field extends about an inch from your body with gradually decreasing effect and can be extended out to other objects with an effort. This allows you to catch bullets, wear clothing, etc. There are no problems with acceleration or similar from your perspective, although you will still exert large forces onto the ground below you.

Supertough again is the same, a field that extends only to your skin. It allows you to massively increase the inertia of everything inside it without increasing gravity. As a result blows or even large vehicles will bounce off you. Going the other way you can jump and increase your inertia as you jump to allow massive leaps.

Supertough part 2 - increase the molecular bonding force of you or an object you are toughing, strengthening it into it's current shape.

Flying - modifying gravity. Again potentially able to extend to other objects to allow them to fly too.

I'm sure you can come up with further effects along these lines but really just playing with material strength, inertia and gravity already lets you do most super-powers.

Comment: If I can modify (all) fundamental constants of the universe, I imagine altering, the right, one or two of them, would allow me to produce an infinite amount of energy or create a humongous gigantic super massive black hole that will suck in all of the universe. Or create a new big bang inside the Andromeda galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your requirements are not directly conflicting - of course you can find such a set of laws. I mean, not you. You certainly not. But a team of scientists could, in a large amount of time.

But does this add anything to your story? Nope. Unless your target audience consists of natural scientists and your story *is* the physical model.

For some ideas about hand waving it away, see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I have to bring this speculation of mine up. Speed-force, other-dimensional based factors aside, there's this peeve that I can't quite put aside. Isn't it impossible for bipedaled humanoids with human sized feet to even reach certain speeds where your skin peels off, your eyes are filled with boiling tears, etc. Purely by guessing, before all that, shouldn't the traction be unable to handle the speed of their legs and they end up sprawling like how you try to run on a slippery surface? Like I said, my science sucks, so I'm just speculating here. Also, putting in some racecar physics. We know that cars that launch too hard, too fast, end up burning rubber more than moving. Could the same thing happen to speedsters as well? And, still, following racecar physics, what if they did a soft launch, set off slower, but still with traction, and gradually accelerated to top speed? And even so, at say, a speed like 300mph for instance, would that previous problem of human feet not gaining enough traction come back to bite them again at that point?

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer as defined in [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If you build up your own world and have questions or doubts on some physical point of view, consider asking a question. This is a Q&A sites, not a discussion forum.

Comment: I was bringing up an issue of speedsters not even being able to reach speeds where other physical boundaries are anticipated. I think it relates closely enough, but in my fault that point was buried in a landslide of personal interests.

Comment: Then consider clarifying your answer to edit out the "landslide of personal interests".